# Find an infinite sequence of statements so that truthness of all sequence elements is unprovable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, turing-machines, incompleteness, collatz-conjecture

Let us consider a function $f: \mathbb N \to \left\{0, 1\right\}$ with finite description length (i.e. describable by a finite length program for a Turing machine) satisfying the following conditions:

1. $f(n)$ is computable in finite time for any $n,$ that means that it is possible to prove that the program for a Turing machine that calculates $f(n)$ always halts;
2. It is impossible to compute in finite time $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n),$ i.e. there is no program for a Turing machine that in finite time checks the fact that $\forall n: f(n) = 1$ and outputs $1$ in this case and $0$ otherwise.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to prove that such function exists or does not exist?
2. If it is possible, are there some concrete examples?

---

Here are some my thoughts.

One possible candidate for such function is $f(n) = I[a_n = 1]$ where $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and $I[\cdot]$ is the indicator function. However for me it is not clear is it possible to prove Collatz conjecture to be unprovable or we couldn't even prove that unprovability.

I would appreciate any reading recommendations on this topic.

Comment: The problem is that a "single instance" problem is always decidable - either the machine $M_0$, which always returns $0$, or the machine $M_1$, which always returns $1$, will compute your product.

Comment: If it is clear that a turing machine halts, it is always possible to determine its output; simply run the machine! Concerning the Collatz-conjecture, it is not known whether the Collatz conjecture (supposed, it is true) can be proven. It could even be unproveable within ZFC.A counter-example (if existent) could be proven within the peano axioms. Several claims were made that it is unproveable (this seems to be an unavoidable scenario in the case of a famous open problem), but apparantly the status of decidability is not solved yet.

Comment: @Peter: A starting point for Collatz that grows without bounds without entering a cycle would not necessarily be provable to be so in PA.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I must have mixed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with your function. First, notice that in (1) it's not actually the same to say "$f(n)$ is computable in finite time for every $n$" and "it is provable that the Turing machine computing $f$ halts on every input". A good counterexample is the Turing machine which, regardless of its input, searches for a proof of a contradiction from Peano Arithmetic; this Turing machine always fails to halt (provided PA is consistent) but that fact can't be proven in Peano Arithmetic.

In (2), $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ is a single number (either $1$ or $0$). A single number is always computable, in this case either by the Turing machine that always outputs $0$ or by the machine that always outputs $1$. Now, we may not be able to decide which one is the right one, but that's a provability question rather than a computability one. In general, in order for it to make sense to say something is noncomputable, you need it to be infinite - usually, an infinite sequence.

On the other hand, you *can* have this: a sequence of binary functions $f_i$ for $i = 0,1,2,\ldots$ so that each $f_i$ is computable, but the sequence $p_i = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}f_i(n)$ is not. For a natural example, let $f_i(n) = 0$ if the $i$th Turing machine halts before stage $n$ and $1$ otherwise. Then $p_i$ is $0$ if the $i$th Turing machine halts or $1$ if it doesn't; that makes computing the $p_i$ equivalent to computing the Halting Problem.

Comment: I think you mean "always *doesn't* halt" in your first paragraph . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber ...So I did. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you the explanation. But what if we replace computability by provability and ask the question about provability? So that $f(n)$ is computable for any $n,$ but it is impossible to prove that $\forall n: f(n) = 1?$ I understand that it depends on set of axioms that you use for proofs, so ideally I want to separately consider case of PA and of ZFC.

Comment: @AlexanderRodin Yes, such an $f$ exists, but again it can't be anything very natural. Let $f$ be the function that checks whether $n$ encodes a proof of a contradiction from $PA$, and outputs $0$ if the answer is "yes" or $1$ otherwise. In $PA$, it's certainly provable that this function is computable and defined everywhere; but by the Incompleteness Theorem, $PA$ can't prove that $f(n)$ is never $0$. And, of course, $PA$ itself wasn't really the important part; you can insert $ZFC$ or a similar system in for $PA$.